# Array generation from a list in python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a list of numbers L.

```
L = [233.0, 0.084, 4.308, 0.0, 2.6208547, 5.1109018, 54.694964, 0.0010984, 54.5804842, 43.473086, 2763.5231162, 28212.5694463, 0.1387176, 0.4591909, 233.0, 0.084, 4.308, 0.0, 2.6208547, 5.1109018, 54.694964, 0.0010984, 54.5804842, 43.473086, 2763.5231162, 28212.5694463, 0.1387176, 0.4591909, 233.0, 0.084, 4.308, 0.0, 2.6208547, 5.1109018, 54.694964, 0.0010984, 54.5804842, 43.473086, 2763.5231162, 28212.5694463, 0.1387176, 0.4591909, 233.0, 0.084, 4.308, 0.0, 2.6208547, 5.1109018, 54.694964, 0.0010984, 54.5804842, 43.473086, 2763.5231162, 28212.5694463, 0.1387176, 0.4591909]
```

This size of the list is based upon a certain variable, for example if n=4, the list will have 56 elements, if n = 5 it will have 70 elements and so on.

I want to generate an array 'a' of length = n. I want `a[0] = L[1]`, `a[1] = L[14]`, `a[2]=L[28]` and so on. I tried using a nested for loop but did not work out well. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you mean `a[0] = L[0]`? Otherwise, you won't get the last element.

Comment: You are looking for slicing `L[::14]`

Comment: @AKS Yes, thats precisely what I was looking for. Stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, easiest one is using slice notation, as mentioned by Joe R's answer. Other options are:

You could've also used the `step` parameter in `range` function:

```
>>> def f(lst, step):
        new_list = []
        for i in range(0,len(lst), step):
            new_list.append(lst[i]))
        return new_list

>>> f(L,14)
[233.0, 233.0, 233.0, 233.0]
```

And if you like List comprehensions, then :

```
>>> [L[i] for i in range(0,len(L), 14)]
[233.0, 233.0, 233.0, 233.0]
```

Alternative to that is using `slice` object:

```
>>> s = slice(0,len(L), 14)
>>> L[s]
[233.0, 233.0, 233.0, 233.0]
```

Comment: This last solution works best since I do need to create other rarrays in the same systematic recursive form from the list. Thank you.

Comment: @Arya .. No pblm...Glad to be of a help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can slice `L` and create a new list `new_list`:

```
new_list = L[::14]
print (new_list)
```

output:

```
[233.0, 233.0, 233.0, 233.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
indices_list = [i*n for i in xrange(n)]
a = [L[index] for index in indices_list]
```

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from array import *
count = 1
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28]
size_of_list = len(list)
my_array = array('i',[])
i = 0
    while (count < size_of_list):
        my_array.append(list[count])
        count = (i+1) *14
        i = i+1
    print my_array
    print "Good bye!"
```

Answer (score 0):

If @AKS is right and you mean `a[0] = L[0]` answer is:

`a = [elem for i, elem in enumerate(L) if i % 14 == 0]`

Comment: NOP...That's not what OP wanted...read question carefully and update your answer with correct fix

Comment: @IronFist fix. Really boner.